# Redshift Serverless Restore from Redshift Snapshot is failing with No Resource Policy

Tags: amazon-redshift, snapshot, amazon-redshift-serverless

I shared a Redshift snapshot from Account A to Account B.

When I try to restore the snapshot in Account B, I am getting an `AccessDenied` exception stating that no resource policy can be found:

[image]

The documentation doesn't mention this error and how to resolve it. I have verified the appropriate KMS permission are in place.

Answer (score 1):

After digging around, I found that you can apply a resource policy to a snapshot. In fairness, the error says there is no resource policy, but there is no mention of needing a resource policy in the documentation I was checking.

After running this from the account where I took the snapshot, the restore worked.

```
aws redshift-serverless \
  put-resource-policy \
  --resource-arn arn:aws:redshift:<region>:<accountid>:snapshot:<redshift-cluster-name>/<snapshot-name> \
  --policy "{\"Version\": \"2012-10-17\", \"Statement\" : [{ \"Sid\": \"AllowUserRestoreFromSnapshot\", \"Principal\":{\"AWS\": [\"<accountid that is restoring the snapshot>\"]}, \"Action\": [\"redshift-serverless:RestoreFromSnapshot\"] , \"Effect\": \"Allow\" }]}"
```